# I installed Samba in /usr/local. How can I run that?

Tags: linux, fedora, samba

how can I run samba if I installed it by this command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make -j4
make install
```

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin/smbd`

Comment: Is it full command?

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, you apparently compiled Samba from source and installed it.

You want to run `samba`, you have to understand that samba is made of three daemons (`smbd`, `nmbd`, and `winbindd`), essentially, and client tools. It is not clear from your question which (deamons or client tools) you mean.

You did not mention which version of Fedora you are running, provide that in the question, please.

If you want to run the daemons:

1. Check to see that you do not already have these deamons running.
2. If you have them running, stop them (how depends on Fedora version you
   run, but `sudo service smbd stop` and `sudo service nmbd` should work just fine, do the equivalent for `winbindd`, if that one is running as well.)
3. Adapt the startup scripts to use the version in `/usr/local/sbin`
   (steps depend on Fedora version)

If you want to use the client tools, add them to your path if they are not already, the ones you want live in `/usr/local/bin`

More information on the deamons can be found on the Centos doc, for example:

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-samba-daemons.html

Answer (score -1):

if the prefix path is not in your profile PATH such as "/usr/local/bin" or "/usr/local/sbin" (which ever location executable is installed to) then you have to specifiy the full path to the executable to run it